# Why is the function $r(n)$ of particular interest in Circle method?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, motivation, goldbachs-conjecture

I was reading Goldbach problem(Ternary version) and encountered the Hardy-Littlewood circle method.In this method,we work with a number $r(n)=\sum\limits_{n=n_1+n_2+n_3}\Lambda(n_1)\Lambda(n_2)\Lambda(n_3)$ where $\Lambda$ is the Von Mangoldt function.I want to know why we are working with such an expression.What is the underlying idea that motivated us to work with this quantity?

Comment: It counts the number of expressions of $n$ as a sum of three primes, weighted by the size of the primes. Analytic number theorists have learned by experience that weighting primes by $\Lambda$ often results in more tractable expressions than just counting the primes.

Comment: $\sum_{p\le x}1\sim x/\log x$ whereas $\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\sim x$. You can surely work with $\sum_{n=p_1+p_2+p_3}1$ instead of $r(n)$, but it will be necessary to tackle with some logarithms in the denominators